Why is 3-tuple (0, 2, 4) not admissible?
I've been reading about k-tuple admissibility and here was the definition that I've read:

In order for a k-tuple to have infinitely many positions at which all
of its values are prime, there cannot exist a prime p such that the
tuple includes every different possible value modulo p. For, if such a
prime p existed, then no matter which value of n was chosen, one of
the values formed by adding n to the tuple would be divisible by p, so
there could only be finitely many prime placements (only those
including p itself). For example, the numbers in a k-tuple cannot take
on all three values 0, 1, and 2 modulo 3; otherwise the resulting
numbers would always include a multiple of 3 and therefore could not
all be prime unless one of the numbers is 3 itself. A k-tuple that
satisfies this condition (i.e. it does not have a p for which it
covers all the different values modulo p) is called admissible.

But then there was the following example:

Although (0, 2, 4) is not admissible it does produce the single set of
primes, (3, 5, 7).

And here I don't understand why this 3-tuple (0, 2, 4) is not admissible. What is the prime p such that this tuple includes every different possible value modulo p?

$p = 3$ does work.

The text you wrote has the answer: " the numbers in a $k$-tuple cannot take on all three values $0$, $1$, and $2$ modulo $3$"

@Sven-OleBehrend Thank you! So (0, 2, 4) will be (0, 2, 1) modulo 3, right?
